# Узнать из метода, какой поток в него заходит

Tags: java, многопоточность

Допустим есть некоторый метод класса. Можно ли прямо из кода этого метода узнать, какой поток в него заходит?

Интересуют именно программные средства, а не отладочный `threaddump` среды разработки.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, можно.

Для того чтобы получить *текущий* поток, достаточно вызвать статический метод `currentThread()` класса `Thread`. Например, код:

```
Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
System.out.println(currentThread.getName());
System.out.println(currentThread.getPriority());
```

Выведет на консоль название текущего потока и его приоритет.